# Tableau, Multi-Step - Split a string column then group the new columns into a single dimension to count results

Tags: salesforce, tableau-api, salesforce-lightning, tableau-desktop

The question is difficult to describe. If it is relevant, my Tableau is connected to Salesforce. Here are the steps I've taken and result I am looking for -

1. I have a text field where up to 37-categories can be listed in any order:

[Example of Original Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tll3G.png)

Each row can have 1 - 5 records, delimited by ";" which I can split. The result of the (custom) split gives me a different column for each separated string:

[Result of Custom Split](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzy8f.png)

What I am looking for is a single column used as single dimension showing results over a Time dimension. The result would look similar to this, but row-1 would be the row-1 value count ("Call Back") across all of the columns.

[Result I Want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVkud.png)

Any direction would be excellent. Thank you!

Comment: you need one step prior to tableau desktop in order to create that specific column based on the distinct value... is it tableau prep (which comes along with desktop) an option for you?

Comment: What analytical goal are you aiming to achieve with this process? There might be several effective ways to achieve that without all the splitting and recombining you are proposing.

Comment: @FabioFantoni - Great question, data prep is incredibly limited with my data connection is directly to Salesforce. 

The best I can do is join individual Salesforce tables to one of the Salesforce objects but cannot manipulate either the individual tables or objects (i.e **Customers" object would include pre-determined Customer-related tables, pre-packaged).

Manipulating any of the data is limited to what can be done within the worksheet _after_ the data source has pulled in all the records.

Comment: @matt_black - Should have started there, thank you.

I want to know the count of complaint tags from all cases tagged (one-case can have up to 37-tags, stored in one field, delimited by **;**  for my tableau audience be able to make comparisons for actionable vs systemic issues we can resolve. 

I.e., of 400-records, 45-included [complaint tag] or the 45-records with [complaint tag], 23-records also had [complaint tag-2] as well.

Data prep is next impossible, my options are limited to worksheet functions/etc.

Comment: Often you’ll want to follow splitting a column like this, with a pivot to get one data row for each split value + original row. Then follow with a data source filter to eliminate empty (null) splits. You can do all that on the data source page - or in Prep if you prefer. Just be careful to avoid double counting other columns.